# MySQL Composite Table JOIN QUERY

Tags: mysql, xampp, rdbms

```
----------      ----------      ----------  
| TBL_1  |      | TBL_2  |      | TBL_3  |  
----------      ----------      ----------  
| id     |      | id     |      |TBL_1_id|  
| foo    |      | bar    |      |TBL_2_id|
----------      ----------      ----------
```

I, kinda, have this particular set of tables in MySQL. TBL_3 is a composite table binding rows in TBL_1 and TBL_2 together. I wanna output contents of TBL_1 and TBL_2 by querying TBL_3 but I can't seem to grasp the concept of `JOIN`s.
Based on what I've read, it should be somewhat like this:

> SELECT * FROM tbl_3
>   RIGHT JOIN (tbl_1, tbl_2) ON (tbl_1.id=tbl_3.tbl_1_id,
>   tbl_2.id=tbl_3.tbl_2_id)
>   WHERE tbl_3.id='some_id';

I am getting nothing. also, as I tweak that query, sometimes rows are returned but never displayed IDK why. why is this?

**Is the above query, same as this?

> SELECT * FROM tbl_3
>   RIGHT JOIN tbl_1 ON tbl_1.id=tbl_3.tbl_1_id
>   RIGHT JOIN tbl_2 ON tbl_2.id=tbl_3.tbl_1_id
>   WHERE tbl_3.id='some_id';

**EDIT: in interpreting the query above w/ the multiple joins, is the *left table* being referred by the 2nd `RIGHT JOIN` the returned table that is the product of the 1st `RIGHT JOIN`?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: i wanna output tbl_1.`foo` and tbl_2.`bar`...

Comment: do you want to output tbl_1.foo regardless of whether there is a matching tbl_2.bar when using tbl_3?  If so, you have to use outer joins.  If not, use an equijoin (plain "join") against tbl_3, tbl_1 and tbl_2.  In the case of inner joins, you need to use tbl_3 as the fact table.  In the case where there may not be tbl_2 values, you will need to join tbl_1 outer to tbl_3 and tbl_2.

Comment: @TGray contents of t1 and t2 don't need to match. so long as t3 points to some t1 and t2 record, I'd output that.

Comment: The question was more along the lines of "do you want tbl_1.foo to show regardless of whether there's a match in tbl_3 (and therefore tbl_2?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query is alone the lines of what you could use to show information from `TBL_1` and `TBL_2` for all `id` pairs which appear in the bridge table `TBL_3`:

```
SELECT t1.foo, t2.bar
FROM TBL_1 t1
INNER JOIN TBL_3 t3
    ON t1.id = t3.TBL_1_id
INNER JOIN TBL_2 t2
    ON t2.id = t3.TBL_2_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.foo, t2.bar
FROM TBL_1 t1
left join TBL_3 t3
    ON t1.id = t3.TBL_1_id
left JOIN TBL_2 t2
    ON t2.id = t3.TBL_2_id;
```